# If two functions have the same divergence and curl in some region, then are they equal?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

If two functions have the same divergence and curl in some region, then are the functions equal?

Comment: Consider subtraction of one from the other.  Can you find a function which has zero divergence and zero curl in some region, but is not itself always zero?

Comment: And read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_vector_field and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036213

Comment: @Henry, a constant function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then their difference will have the same divergence and curl. So you are asking whether
a vector field of zero divergence and curl is necessarily zero.

There a trivial counterexamples to this; for instance a constant vector field.

There are less trivial examples too. If $f$ is a harmonic function, its gradient
has divergence zero (essentially the definition of harmonic function) while
every gradient has curl zero. So you can take the gradient of a harmonic function.
There are lots of harmonic functions...

Comment: Thanks, however if it's given that the function goes to zero at infinity, then are the functions equal?

Comment: Depends on your domain and dimension. In $\Bbb R^3$ the function $1/\|x\|$ is harmonic and goes to $0$ at infinity.